# Please Help A Mega Beginner Incorporate Gamecenter Into Cocos2d game (Twee Jump.)

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone, gamekit, game-center

I am using twee jump (source code here: https://github.com/haqu/tweejump) as the basis for my first iPhone game on cocos2d, but i've had a great deal of difficulty incorporating game-center into twee jump. I've used GKTapper, and a truckload of other stuff, but no results. I would highly appreciate if you masters of Obj-c would download the source code, and just tell me how to get logged in into gamecenter (just to show the little icon that says: Welcome, yourname)

Please, I WOULD HIGHLY APPRECIATE IT (IM CRYING HERE :'()

Thanks in advance,
patoma16

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you take a look at the GKHelper class, made by Steffen Itterheim, located in the following demo project:

http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2011/01/game-kit-data-sendreceive-demo-project/

By studying the source code you should be able to get some quick results that may encourage you to dig deeper into the subject.

Take a look at Apple's documentation as well (don't skim it, study it): http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/GameCenterOverview/GameCenterOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH5-SW7.